# Error when install Laravel Cashier with Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

I installed creatydev/plans (v1.0.0) on Laravel Framework 10.25.2.

After, I tryied to install Cashier, but I received a error.

The stripe version installed by creatydev/plans is >= 12.1 and Laravel Cashier need strip version v10.21.0.

Error:

1 - Command: composer require creatydev/plans

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine                                                                                                                                                                                                
./composer.json has been updated                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Running composer update creatydev/plans                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Updating dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Problem 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    - Root composer.json requires creatydev/plans * -> satisfiable by creatydev/plans[v1.0.0].                                                                                                                                                         
    - creatydev/plans v1.0.0 requires stripe/stripe-php >=12.1 -> found stripe/stripe-php[v12.1.0, ..., v12.5.0] but the package is fixed to v10.21.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.                                                                                                             
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require creatydev/plans:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require creatydev/plans:^2.1" if you know which you need.        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

2 - Command: composer require creatydev/plans --with-all-dependencies

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine                                                                                                                                                                                                
./composer.json has been updated                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Running composer update creatydev/plans --with-all-dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                        
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Updating dependencies                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Problem 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    - Root composer.json requires creatydev/plans * -> satisfiable by creatydev/plans[v1.0.0].                                                                                                                                                         
    - creatydev/plans v1.0.0 requires stripe/stripe-php >=12.1 -> found stripe/stripe-php[v12.1.0, ..., v12.5.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require creatydev/plans:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require creatydev/plans:^2.1" if you know which you need.        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

How could I deal with whis error?